# libre office calc: Changing the interval that labels display at

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a 2 column spreadsheet. The first column is a label, the second is a value. I want to make a chart that displays every single label on the y axis but by default calc displays the labels at intervals, like every 5th one. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the axis when in chart edit mode. To do so:

1. Double-click on the chart; after this, there's a light grey border around the chart, telling you that you've activeted chart edit mode:

   [image]
2. Open Menu "`Format`" -> "`Axis...`" -> "`X Axis`" (or Y axis, depending o the layout of your chart):

   [image]
3. In the Axis Format window, select the "`Label`" tab:

   [image]
4. Set the label formatting as desired. The optimal format settings depend on the labels. If they aren't too long, staggering the labels may help. If they don't fit even staggered, then you could modify the text direction, e.g. settiing it to 45 degrees.